# Calculate unique alias before flushing entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I have an entity with a field, not included to a form, but calculated basing on other fields values, which come with input.
Currently the value is set in a lifecycle callback:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function prePersist() {...}
```

I want keep this value unique in scope of the DB table column, and modify it before saving, until it is one and only one.

- I tried to use `UniqueEntity`, but in time of entity's object creation the field's value is NULL (unknown). So it stays after a form submit, in time of validation. When `prePersist()` is actually called, the value appears and goes to the DB without validation.
- I may try to get an `EntityRepository` instance, and try make checks as SQL queries from `prePersist()`, but it looks extremely ugly.
- I may try to use a kind of hash function, like md5, or sha1 which mostly guarantee the values uniqueness, but hash functions have collisions, and I'd like keep that value "human readable".

Please propose to me a "Symfony"-style solution for this case.

Comment: I don't really understand what is your need. Do you want a good way to generate a uniq and readable identifier automatically created and assigned to each new entry ?

Comment: What do you mean with "Human Readable"? Which format will you like?

Comment: Yes, I need a way of unique readable identifier generation, based on user input. If it is possible, it should be updated on DB record edit, and still unique in any case. And "human readable" means easy to read and memorize (possibly partially), if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to answers and comments in this topic, I was able to realize that I'm solving a task which conflicts with Symfony2 architecture:

- get user input from form
- validate the input
- calculate automatic fields
- **validate again**

The acceptable solution looks like a combination of proposed approaches, including some tricks for "human readability": the alias is concatenated from a subset of the form's parameters after input validation by such scheme:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function prePersist()
{
   ...
   $alias = "{$param1}-{$param2}-...-{$paramN}-" . md5(time() . rand(0, 9));
   ...
}
```

So it is unique because `md5()` is attached to the end, concatenated params significantly reduce the risk of collision. And even if we change a parameter from the list (for example in case of user update an entity with edit form), the value stills unique. In addition we got sanitized, but readable and having a sense parameters at the alias begin, which helps to memorizing in  case of manual investigations.

A disadvantage of the solution is variable length, which depends on parameters. But they may be shortened to the fixed length.

Comment: You should accept your answer, it's a clean approach that fits your need.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is : Use the [doctrine GUID/UUID generator](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies).

But, it can be only used as an identifier, out, you want a simple field.

Also, what I propose is a bit complicated for a little need, I understand that you don't want write a lot of code and have a complex schema.

Create a specific entity with the custom identifier :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */ 
class UniqIdentifier
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

And add the following in your entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UniqIdentifier", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $uniqId;
```

Comment: It's an interesting approach, thank you. It's a pity, but it doesn't allow include user data from request to UUID generated (I call it "human readability", and use for manual incidents investigations - much easy to read if alias contains some words in addition to hash, or something else).

Answer (score 1):

to avoid null value during instance create :  (does'nt guarantee an unique id )

```
md5(uniqid(rand(), true))
```

and in order to keep always a unique value :

```
md5(uniqid($your_user_login, true))
```

or

```
md5(uniqid($entity_id, true))
```

Comment: I agree with such approach. `time() . rand()` also gives unique id. But the alias is too senseless  - hard to search and investigate some cases manually.

Comment: what do you mean by alias ? entity_id ?

Comment: Alias for me is an alternative to entity_id, which is used for purposes, when using of integer id is ineffective, or insecure.

Comment: Your solution inspired me for the answer I gave myself for my question, thank you.